# How to always accept javascript alert from Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to configure Selenium WebDriver so that javascript alerts are always accepted?

I am testing an application that requests the user to confirm deletion from a javascript pop-up alert dialog.

I would like it so that alerts are always accepted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

> inject javascript to handle the alert / confirms yourself (although you'll need to do this after every page refresh before the alert shows up and you won't be able to handle alerts that are onload)
>
> `( (JavascriptExecutor) driver ).executeScript("window.alert = function(){}");`
>
> or
>
> `(JavascriptExecutor) driver ).executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true;}");`

https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/20#issuecomment-13621554